# Does barrier damage count towards Orisa's "Overclocked" achievement?

Tags: achievements, overwatch

The description for Overwatch's '*Overclocked*' is "***Amplify 900 damage with a single use of Orisa's Supercharger in Quick or Competitive Play***"

Does damage dealt to barriers count towards this achievement? For example, if I used [Orisa's Supercharger](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Orisa#Supercharger) and my team dealt 900 damage to [Reinhardt's Barrier Field](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Reinhardt#Barrier_Field), would that unlock the achievement?

[image: Orisa's 'Overclocked' achievement]

Comment: The bigger issue here is getting people who actually deal damage while your ult is down :P

Comment: A good followup to this question would be if damage to armour counts as the original damage or the damage minus the effect of armour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, according to [TrueAchievements](https://www.trueachievements.com/a231639/overclocked-achievement), damage to barriers will count towards the Overclocked achievement.

> You must amplify 900 damage. Damage to barriers will count towards this, but damage into D.Va's Defense Matrix will not as it doesn't apply damage to anything.

Comment: D.Va at it again...